# CMake Beginner's Question: project with 3rd party library gets not compiled

Tags: c++, cmake, xml-rpc

So I am struggeling with cmake for some time now. I want to use the xmlrpc-c library from [here](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/). So I started a new project with main.cpp and CMakeLists.txt and copied the xmlrpc-c as a subdirectory into my project (since xmlrpc-c is unfortunately not a cmake library):

My code is exactly a example from [here](https://vorbrodt.blog/2019/03/23/xml-rpc/) and looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "xmlrpc-c/include/xmlrpc-c/base.hpp"
#include "xmlrpc-c/include/xmlrpc-c/registry.hpp"
#include "xmlrpc-c/include/xmlrpc-c/server_abyss.hpp"

using namespace std;

class hello : public xmlrpc_c::method
{
public:
    void execute(const xmlrpc_c::paramList& params, xmlrpc_c::value* retval)
    {
        string msg(params.getString(0));
        params.verifyEnd(1);

        cout << msg << endl;

        *retval = xmlrpc_c::value_string("XMLRPC server says hello!");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    xmlrpc_c::registry registry;
    registry.addMethod("hello", new hello);

    xmlrpc_c::serverAbyss server(xmlrpc_c::serverAbyss::constrOpt().registryP(&registry).portNumber(8080));
    server.run();

    return 1;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(xmlrpc_c_server C CXX)

add_executable(xmlrpc_c_server main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(xmlrpc_c_server -lxmlrpc++ -lxmlrpc_server++ -lxmlrpc_server_abyss++ -lxmlrpc_util++)
```

The problem I have is that my build-process fails with a linker-error: as far as I understand is the header file `registry.hpp` not included correctly. If I comment out the code line `registry.addMethod("hello", new hello);`, I can compile the program without any errors.

```
====================[ Build | xmlrpc_c_server | Debug ]=========================
/usr/bin/cmake --build /mnt/c/Users/valentin.ackva/CLionProjects/xmlrp-c-server/cmake-build-debug --target xmlrpc_c_server -- -j 9
Scanning dependencies of target xmlrpc_c_server
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmlrpc_c_server.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable xmlrpc_c_server
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xmlrpc_c_server.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
/mnt/c/Users/struppel/CLionProjects/xmlrp-c-server/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `xmlrpc_c::registry::addMethod(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, xmlrpc_c::method*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmlrpc_c_server.dir/build.make:84: xmlrpc_c_server] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/xmlrpc_c_server.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/xmlrpc_c_server.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: xmlrpc_c_server] Error 2
```

What is missing?

Comment: `target_link_directories(target PRIVATE the_lib_dir)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the library you want to use doesn't have a `cmake` project you need to handle this on your own. I would suggest using `add_subdirectory` and creating a sub-project, where you build the library (either as shared or static depending on your needs).

In addition you need to point `cmake` to the location of the headers. Try manually adding what's missing to the `add_executable` or use `include_directories` and adjust your `#include`s accordingly.

You can also use some unofficial `cmake` version of it like [this one](https://github.com/ifm/xmlrpc-c). If you are using `git` you can add the repo as a submodule and integrate the code from that repo into your main project.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to CMake maybe it's worth looking at a tutorial instead?

https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/

I think it would help your confusion a lot.